# Program works in OnlineGDB but not in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This program (for now) reads a 10000-line .txt file and writes it in the console. In Visual Studio 2022 Community it outputs -842150451 every line. I decided to check it in onlinegdb, there it works properly (both in "C++" and "C++ 20" compilers). What can be the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //setlocale(0, "Russian");
    ifstream file;
    file.open("17.txt");
    int* list=new int [10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        file >> list[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        cout << list[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: My ***guess***? You fail to open the file. Always check for operations that can fail. That includes not only opening the file but also reading from it.

Comment: VS said that too much is stored in the stack, so I changed it from static to dynamic.

Comment: If you want to allocate dynamically, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: You're right. I added the line  `if (file.is_open()){cout << "good"<<endl;}`, it wrote "good" in OnlineGDB but not in VS.

Comment: It turned out that in VS I connected the file to the project but it wasn't added into the project's folder. When I added it there manually, it worked. Thanks for your help!